# C++ delete/destructor safe call

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, destructor

I have a "twisted" question...
Suppose to have a class like

```
class MyClass {
public:
 MyClass();
 ~MyClass();
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& obj); 
private:
  int* mem;
};
```

where basically `MyClass` inits somehow `mem` (with a `new` call), the `~MyClass()` deallocates `mem` with the `delete` operator.
Suppose moreover the operator `=` is overloaded with the code

```
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& obj) {
 if(this != &obj) {
   //allocate memory of "this" with the "new" operator and copy "obj" data;
 }
return *this;
}
```

my question is basically the following... With the following sequence of statements

```
//statement 1 for short
MyClass my_obj = some_obj_of_MyClass;
```

i guess everything is fine since the operator `=` allocates memory and copies the data, but with the following

```
//statement 2 for short
MyClass obj; //allocate memory for "mem" 
obj = some_obj_of_MyClass;
```

if think it is not correct the implementation i proposed since i don't delete memory allocated early. I could call the destructor inside the assignment operator block, but in that case probably the statement 1 wouldn't be safe.

So what it is a safe way to implement everything?
I guess the problem here can be to understand when the destructor is called or how to implement it properly.

Comment: Your first example uses the copy constructor, not `operator=`. In `operator=` it's guaranteed that `this` refers to an already-constructed object.

Comment: `//statement 1` runs a (compiler-generated) copy constructor, *not* a (user-defined) assignment operator. It'll just set `my_obj.mem` to the same value as `some_obj_of_MyClass.mem`, so you'll have two objects pointing to the same memory, and eventually double destruction. So no, it's not fine. See also: [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: Is `//statement 1` equivalent to `MyClass obj(some_obj_of_MyClass)`?

Comment: either use smart pointers(unique_ptr or shared_ptr), or just call delete inside the assignment operator

Answer (score 0):

Your code violates the rule of three: Whenever a class provides a custom

1. copy constructor
2. copy assignment operator
3. destructor

it should likely provide all three. Because, if any of these is omitted, it is possible to construct use cases where bad things happen. For example, contrary to intuition, the statement

```
MyClass my_obj = some_obj_of_MyClass;
```

does not call the assignment operator. It calls the copy constructor, which you have not provided. As such, the default copy constructor is used which simply copies the pointer. Once either `my_obj` or `some_obj_of_MyClass` is destructed, the other will have a pointer to the deleted memory region.

On the other hand, the statements

```
MyClass obj;
obj = some_obj_of_MyClass;
```

will first default construct `obj`, and then call the assignment operator on it. The assignment operator must be written in a way that it works correctly in every possible state of `obj` (i. e. it must not leak memory or double delete memory). That is, if `obj.mem` is allocated, the assignment operator must either reuse that memory or deallocate it (possibly replacing it with a new allocation). If `obj.mem` can be a null pointer, then the assignment operator must include special handling of this special case.

So, your choice is basically, whether you want to allow the `mem` pointer to become a null pointer, If you don't allow this, your default constructor must allocate a dummy memory region that can be deallocated by the assignment operator.

---

You can also work around the rule of three by deleting the unimplemented functions. Your class could be declared like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& obj); 
    ~MyClass();
private:
    int* mem;
};
```

This would disallow the statement

```
MyClass my_obj = some_obj_of_MyClass;
```

forcing user code to use the more verbose

```
MyClass obj;
obj = some_obj_of_MyClass;
```

but which makes the implementation of `MyClass` a bit simpler.